# IDW Interpolation in QGIS gives weird values

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted

I'm trying to do an IDW interpolation with QGIS tool.
But I'm really surprised by results. Interpolation values aren't similar as shape values.
I used a power of 0.2 to get a smooth raster.
Somebody have an idea ?

[>>Here are data<<](https://we.tl/Gx88LsiS2m)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This really doesn't tell us enough to help you. How many values are there more than 540? What is the spatial distribution of values (map would be good)? Have you tried this with other tools to see if the issue is QGIS specific?

Comment: Yes, i'll give you some details. I tried SAGA idw and it always crash with `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details`. I add in my post 2 screen shots to describes values distribution.

Comment: it looks quite normal, most of data points are below 1080, but there are some outlayers. What are you interpolating? why do you want the outlayers in your raster?

Comment: I'm interpolating vines biomasse. I don't understand why values ​​under 540 aren't represented when there are many. And what do you mean about **outlayers**?

Comment: By the looks of your sample image, you have plenty of points under 540 represented - can you explain what you mean when you say they aren't represented.  Also your IDW legend shows a truncated scale of 539.15 and below.  If you are expecting values above this, try recalculating statistics.

Comment: Sorry a mistake in my remarks, I reformulate. I have plenty of points under 522 represented but in my interpolation, values start at 522. And it's the same above 539... standard deviation is between 215 and 844.

Comment: Can you make the data available?

Comment: I add a link in my post to download it on wetransfer.

Comment: @GoMer "outlayers" is bad English for [outliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier)

Comment: I think it depends on what smooth means for you. The P value plays a key rol, but the size of the cell also plays a key one for interpolation result in a raster. What is cell size you think matches your needs and data?

Comment: A cell size of 1 meter will be great. But I don't know where adjust this parameter... In Qgis interpolation you can only adjust final image size. For exemple 3000 x 3000.

Comment: You can use interpolation plugin which has option to adjust cellsize

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, The histogram shows correct range of the data. But you have selected cumulative count cut in style manager, that's why by default min 2% and max 2% have been truncated from the range. Choose the min/max option to see the whole range in the legend as well as map.
[image]

Comment: I already use min/max